# Jump out of deeply recursive function call

Tags: parsing, exception, recursion, swift

I wrote a parser in Objective-C about a **highly ambiguous language**. Everything works fine. I often jump out of many function calls with throwing an exception (I keep being in my code, so the exception will never get out of the parser).

I thought of porting the code to Swift, then I noticed that there is no exception handling in Swift.

**I don't want exception handling nor do I need it**, but the jumping out of many **different nested  function** calls came in handy while **writing parsers**.

Is there a good way instead of the jump of exceptions to the `@catch` block in Swift?

---

Example of recursive function, to make it more clear (working playground code):

```
import Foundation

func addToSum(sum: Int, rest: String) -> Int {
    if rest == "" {
        return sum
    } else {
        if rest[rest.endIndex.predecessor()] != "i" {
            // can't throw exception, if scratches is like "iiiiiiiiiiiioiiiiii"
        }

        var shorterRest = rest.substringToIndex(rest.endIndex.predecessor())
        return addToSum(sum + 1, shorterRest)
    }
}

let scratches = "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
var sum = addToSum(0, scratches) // sum is 11 ;-)
```

I know the example isn't that good because it is only one function and you could easily add an error, but then I had to go every function call back.

Please see the bigger picture. I don't need backtracing in the parser.

---

[Here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4997) is a link that has the same problem: Use exceptions as flow control in parsers. Unfortunately it doesn't give an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you are using exceptions as flow control statements. While this is considered best practice in some languages, it is discouraged in Objective-C. It should just be used for fatal errors. Now some might argue that parsing errors are fatal, but I don't think so. They are easily to handle with other techniques.

Comment: @vikingosegundo In parsers I have only seen exceptions as flow control, because the performance is better than to step through all functions on the stack. And much easier to handle if the stack is very big.

Comment: Combining recursion and exertions must create a enormous stack, as with every recursion step the stack is copied several times.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Of course only very special expression would get the catch block, so the jump is to the next speculated expression is fast. I know it is a special case, because it is about parsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is handled pretty easily in this case by returning an Optional. Instead of throwing an exception, just return `nil` and let it propagate back up the chain.

```
func addToSum(sum: Int, rest: String) -> Int? {
    if rest == "" {
        return sum
    } else {
        if rest[rest.endIndex.predecessor()] != "i" {
            return nil
        }

        var shorterRest = rest.substringToIndex(rest.endIndex.predecessor())
        return addToSum(sum + 1, shorterRest)
    }
}

let scratches = "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
var sum = addToSum(0, scratches)  // sum is 21, actually
sum = addToSum(0, "iiiioiii")     // sum is now nil
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear. It is very tedious to step through all the functions calls and check again for the values, especially if there are many different dynamically created functions in a parser. The performance would be bad. Because every time when I would speculate in the wrong expression all of the subexpressions must be undone, that would be not as good performance with your solution. But maybe that is the only way.

Comment: I think it's the only way right now. Perhaps a different language calls for a different way of thinking about the problem. Alexandros Salazar has a two-part post on error handling in Swift that is a great read: [part 1](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/error-handling-in-swift), [part 2](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/error-handling-in-swift-part-ii).

Comment: It is not really an error, more of a flow control on big stacks with parsers. The example is not the code I need to fix. It should only serve as a recursion example. All the parsers I have seen on Objective-C use that technique. I see exceptions and goto is not the correct way. Maybe you are right, the time of the hacks are over ;-)

Comment: @ViktorLexington Just my 2 cents: if you talk about a parser and speed, you shouldn't really consider Objective-C anyway. I would guess, that the performance of Swift will not suffer from returning an  Optional. The performance of your Objective-C code returning nil instead of throwing an exception is likely even faster. However a parser in Objective-C will be slow with exceptions and without compared to an optimized C++ implementation ;)